# A bag contains 3 red balls and 4 blue balls. Find the probability of picking at random two balls of a) the same color b)different colors

Tags: probability

A bag contains $3$ red balls and $4$ blue balls. Find the probability of picking, at random, two balls of

a) the same color

b) different colors

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange! You may find this tour helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour. The MathJax summary is quite helpful: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Answer (score 2):

Answers by @Mandar, @Zack, and @David are in agreement, clear, and correct (+1's).

I just wanted to show you the role of the 'hypergeometric distribution' in solving
problems such as this. Let $X$ be the number of red balls in two draws without replacement. Then
$$P(X = k) = \frac{{3 \choose k}{4 \choose {2-k}}}{{7 \choose 2}},$$
for $k = 0, 1, 2.$
The two balls are of the same color if $X = 0$ or $2$, and of different
colors if $X = 1$.

You can get the numerical values of the probabilities by evaluating the
'binomial coefficients', or by using software. In R statistical software
the computation is as follows:

```
 k = 0:2;  pdf=dhyper(k, 3, 4, 2)
 cbind(k, pdf, 7*pdf)
 #     k       pdf  
 #[1,] 0 0.2857143 2
 #[2,] 1 0.5714286 4
 #[3,] 2 0.1428571 1
```

Ignore the row numbers in brackets. The PDF column shows the three
probabilities as decimal fractions. The last column indicates that these
probabilities are $2/7, 4/7,$ and $1/7.$ So $P(\mathrm{Same\; Color}) = 3/7$
and $P(\mathrm{Different\; Color}) = 4/7.$

Perhaps you have seen the hypergeometric distribution already, and
perhaps you will encounter it later in your course. Either way, the
most difficult thing about it may be the name 'hypergeometric'.

Answer (score 1):

b) Probability of different is probability of red on first (3/7) times probability of blue given a red has been chosen (4/6), plus the probability of blue on first (4/7) times probability of red given a blue has been chosen (3/6), or:  4/7.

You can do a) by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of picking 2 blues balls (lol) is 4/7 times 3/6 which is 2/7. The probability of picking 2 red balls is 3/7 times 2/6 which is 1/7. Thus the probability of picking two same colored balls is 3/7 (The sum of the two). Thus the probability of picking different colored balls is 1-3/7 which is 4/7.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is important to note here that the order in which balls are chosen does not matter.

The total number of ways of drawing 2 balls out of 7 is 7C2 i.e. 21

For first case we either draw 2 red (3C2) or 2 blue balls (4C2), for total favorable cases of 9

Hence probability of drawing same color balls is $\frac{9}{21}$

The probability of drawing different color balls is therefore $1-\frac{9}{21}=\frac{12}{21}$